# Independence with boost random

Tags: c++, boost, random

I am trying to use mersenne twister to generate samples from various distribution. I have one generator and it is used to generate all of them. Something strange (to me at least) happens here. On one hand calculating the correlation coefficient of the various samples gives me almost zero, which seems nice. But when I change a parameter of one distribution (which is used nowhere else), it somehow also changes the results I get in others. Specifically:

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>

using namespace boost; // boost random library for random generators

mt19937 generator(7687); // mersenne twister random number generator, seed = 7687

double normal_sample(double mu, double sigma)
// returns a sample from normal distribution with mean mu and variance sigma 
{
    normal_distribution<> norm_dist;
    variate_generator<mt19937&, normal_distribution<> > norm_rnd(generator, norm_dist);

    return(mu + sigma * norm_rnd());
}    

double poisson_sample(double intensity)
// returns a number of points in a realization of a Poisson point process
{
    poisson_distribution<> poiss_dist(intensity);
    variate_generator<mt19937&, poisson_distribution<> > poiss_rnd(generator, poiss_dist);

    return(poiss_rnd());
}
```

This is the code...the generator part, then I draw from those two distributions, changing the parameter called `intensity`. This changes not only the Poisson sample, but the normal one as well...actually, now that I think of it, it kind of makes sense, because my Poisson sample determines a number of points that are also randomly generated using the same generator...so then then depending on how many of them there are, I get something else, because the normal sample is generated using different numbers in the sequence. Is that correct?

If so, how would one go about changing that? Should I use multiple generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that depending on the parameters fewer or more random samples are extracted from the mersenne twister.

This logically implies that all other results are shifted, making all other outcomes different.

> [...] *it kind of makes sense, because my Poisson sample determines a number of points that are also randomly generated using the same generator...so then then depending on how many of them there are, I get something else, because the normal sample is generated using different numbers in the sequence. Is that correct?*

Seems to me you got it figured out already, yes.

If you wanted repeatable PRNG, use separate PRNG states, i.e. different mersenne egnines.

Comment: I read elsewhere on stackexchange that using more than one generator sometimes not quite the best idea. If I use say 5 generators with different seeds, can I be sure the generated sequences are not overlapping? Or are there any guidelies to choose seeds in this case (perhaps large seeds that are far apart or something)?. I have to confess I have not studied how mersenne twister works exactly, so maybe this is a stupid question :)

Comment: The distance of the seeds clearly shouldn't matter (they could be adjacent for all that matters). Indeed to prevent patterns you should consider using a single gen (although, consider threading...). But, then you have to let go of the "convenience" of having deterministic random streams even when you change distributions for some consumers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Perhaps I can test the code using multiple generators, possibly sacrificing independence (but being able to control what I get in one place when I change parameters somewhere else) for the moment and then switch back to using just one generator when all seems more or less debugged. Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by considering threading...Or what threading means in this context for that matter :)

Comment: You can't use a single generator from multiple threads (without very slow synchronization). Also, I don't it's accurate to say you "sacrifice independence". You "sacrifice" predictability across different configurations. The distributions will make sure of the... distributions, so you sacrifice nothing real.